# Where i get Fulfillment URL?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

[image]

I have tried to create action in google assistance.

I am already adding the name of smart home action and account linking step.

The next step is to add the Fulfillment URL? Where I get this address?

If I want to add action like Light 1, 2,3 on or off where I want to include these details?

Answer (score 0):

The fulfillment URL is the publicly accessible URL that the Google Assistant will call to send commands to turn on and off a bulb, and request service details like the devices that a given user may have.

You should visit and read the [smart home documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/) to understand how to process the requests and generate responses. You should also check out the [sample project](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs) to understand how all the pieces fit together.